# Incorrect displayed width for JQuery UI button

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, button, width

A common way to create a button to access another page (i.e. link) using `JQuery-UI` is the following:

```
<div id="hb">
    <form action="index.html"><input type="submit" value="Home" id="but_hb"></form>
</div>
```

In order to set the width and layout, one can do:

```
$('#but_hb').button().css({ width: 70 });
$('#hb').css({
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 70,
    top:0,
    left:0,
    position:"absolute"
});
```

My question is: why is the displayed width only 68 pixels? How to solve this?

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r73UZ/) for a replication of the issue.

Comment: Seems to be 70px... Did you measure it via on screen or in debug?

Comment: I took a screen shot, then checked in paint.net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add additional styles to your button, your OS (or possibly a plugin) is styling it for you. Add a `background:"#f00"` and `border:"none"` to the CSS then remeasure.

```
$('#hb').css({
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 70,
    top:0,
    left:0,
    position:"absolute",
    background:"#f00",
    border:"none"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 9, the actual width is 64px and the border is 3px on the left and 3px on the right, totaling the intended visible width to 70px. You always have to take the border and padding into account. Padding will expand the element's width. See [The CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Answer (score 1):

70px -2Xborder. The border will depend on your browser unless you define it yourself. [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

[image]